# Vue/Gridsome displaying a loading image while reading a file using Filereader

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js, gridsome

I have setup a form with a number of fields and file upload capability.

I'm trying to display a loading image/text while a file is being read and processed with filereader but this is not quite working.

I am using v-if and 'this.loading' variable to do this.

The image does appear but doesn't disappear once file processing is done. I feel it's something to do with 'this.loading' not being set or picked up correctly?

Please check code below and help if you can.

Edit: setup a codepen but it's not working as it is in my code. The image is coming up immediately here. First time using codepen.

https://codepen.io/jazzybuilds/pen/vYyoYwN

```js
handleAttachment($event) {

  var ready = false;
  this.loading = true;
  console.log(this.loading);
  const _this = this;

  var check = function() {

    if (ready === true) {
      this.loading = false;
      console.log(this.loading);
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(check, 0);
  }

  check();

  var reader = new FileReader()

  reader.onloadend = () => {
    console.log(reader.result);
    this.form.files = reader.result;
    ready = true;
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0])

}
```

```html
<p>
<input type="file" name="file"  @change="handleAttachment($event)"/>
</p>

<p>
<div v-if="loading">
<div class="sk-chase">
<div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
<div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
<div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
<div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
<div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
<div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
</div>
<span>Loading...</span>
</div>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you share a js fiddle or codepen?

Comment: @YashMaheshwari added codepen not sure if that will help though. the image comes up immediately and stays up.